# Customize plot of estaccumR product

Tags: vegan

How do I customize the plot of an estaccumR object so that only S and Chao appear (not ACE) superimposed in a single biplot? Descriptions using both base R and ggplot are appreciated.

Example of estaccum R plot:

```
plot(estaccumR(dune))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out from the "poolaccum" help file how to exclude the ACE plot in base R:

```
plot(estaccumR(dune),display=c("S","Chao"))
```

However, I still don't know of a good way to construct this plot in ggplot (which is my preference). Autoplot() only works for poolaccum objects (not estaccum)

Answer (score 0):

Github package **ggvegan** has functions to display `poolaccum` results in **ggplot** graphics. See https://github.com/gavinsimpson/ggvegan. If these do not do what you want them to do, you are welcome to suggest improvements in GitHub.